# Laravel insert and update many to many relationships between three tables

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following table structure :

**Users Table**

```
user_id
username
password
```

**Roles Table**

```
role_id
role_name
```

**Environments Table**

```
environment_id
environment_name
```

and have a pivot table to keep the relation as follows

**User_Roles_Environments Table**

```
user_id
role_id
environment_id
```

Users can be assigned with multiple roles and can be added to multiple environments.

I have added the following relationships to the model classes

**Environment.php**

```
public function roles() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        'App\Models\Role',
        'user_roles_environments'
    )->withPivot('user_id');
}

 public function users(){
     return $this->belongsToMany(
         'App\Models\User',
         'user_roles_environments'
     )->withPivot('role_id');
 }
```

**User.php**

```
public function environments(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        'App\Models\Environment',
        'user_roles_environments'
    )->withPivot('role_id');
}

public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        'App\Models\Role',
        'user_roles_environments'
    )->withPivot('environment_id');
}
```

**Role.php**

```
public function environments() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        'App\Models\Environment',
        'user_roles_environments'
    )->withPivot('user_id');
}

public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(
        'App\Models\User',
        'user_roles_environments'
    )->withPivot('environment_id');
}
```

Now, is this the correct way of defining the relationships as per the table structure ? When I save the user, I am giving the corresponding role_ids (multiple roles can be selected) and environment_ids(multiple environments can be selected). I tried the following code to attach the relationship.

```
foreach($request->input('user_roles') as $userRole) {
     $user->roles()->attach($userRole);
 }
 foreach($request->input('user_role_environments') as $userEnvironment) {
     user->environments()->attach($userEnvironment);
 }
```

where, the input gives `role_ids` and `environment_ids`. But I am getting the following SQL error :

> message: "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'role_role_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into
>   `user_roles_environments` (`role_role_id`, `user_user_id`) values
>   (ROLE_ID, 0))

Here only two fields are appearing. How can I add `environment_id` to it ?

Answer (score 0):

So I assume that the number of user roles are same as the number of environments.
I will count the number of user roles and use the count to do a for loop. In the loop I can use the count as the limit of my loop.
This should solve your problem.

```
$user_role_count=count($request->input('user_roles'));

for($i=0;$i<$user_role_count;$i++){

$user->roles()->attach($request->user_roles[$i],['environment_id' => $request->user_role_environments[$i]]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the custom column names that you may have inside the table.

Like the following (taken from [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)):

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role', 'role_user', 'user_id', 'role_id');
```